# Add current year to regex expression

Tags: angularjs, regex

I have this regex expression in angularjs that only allow years from 2019 to 9999.

```
ng-pattern="/(?:2019|20[2-9][0-9]|2[1-9][0-9]{2}|[3-9][0-9]{3})/"
```

How can i change the 2019 to a dynamic year? i tried doing this but its not working.

```
ng-pattern="/(?:{{CurrentYear}}|20[2-9][0-9]|2[1-9][0-9]{2}|[3-9][0-9]{3})/"
```

And also i want to add to the regex to restrict the user from adding special characters. Thanks guys.

Comment: In the general case, you can't patch your regex this way.  The pattern implicitly has to "know" what the year range would be, and this would change with each passing year.

Comment: Why not make use of [`input[range]`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Brange%5D)?